# Run query against Amazon Redshift and an on-premises source at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

We are working with an Amazon Redshift cluster and for sure our on-premise source data. Sometimes we need to run queries combining Redshift and on-premises data. To explore my data in both sources I work with DataGrip.

I know that SQL has functions like [OpenQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that can query different DB sources in the same transaction. I'm wondering whether DataGrip could do that or how else could I try to reach out in a query to Redshift and on-premises?

Comment: Did you try to plug it as an external schema in Redshift?

Comment: How could I do that? @moscas

Comment: Please, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a couple of options

1. Use a bi tool that enables data federation, there are a few of
   these. for example you may be able to use amazon quicksight. (this
   would not be sql though)
2. If possible, mirror your onsite data to s3 and then use redshift
   spectrum to join to that data